# Hiding "Spaces" element in VSCode status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to hide "Spaces" element in VSCode status bar?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from VSCode 1.36 (June 2019), it is possible to hide any status bar elements (including those provided by extensions) by right-clicking on the status bar and selecting the desired element:

[image: Hiding status bar element from context menu]

The configuration persists across all workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

The only status bar item that can be removed through built-in settings is the feedback icon via the `workbench.statusBar.feedback.visible` setting.

There are open GitHub issues pending, requesting more customization in the status bar. [Here's one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35744) related to the location of the items. And [here's another](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3874) related to the removal of items.

Note that the last issue offers a [solution in the comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3874#issuecomment-404161826), which recommends that you install the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension, allowing you to target and hide the items via CSS classes.